# Casting Interface{} to specific Type

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to make a generic function for saving to the datastore. The second of the following two examples works, but the first gives me a "datastore: invalid entity type" error.

I'm vastly ignorant about Go at the moment, but attempting to decrease my ignorance. Is there some way to cast object in the first example into a type the name of which is held in a string. Eg some kind of reflection. I tried reflect.ValueOf, but failed with it.

Thanks in advance

Example 1:

```
func save(kind string, c.appengine.Context, object interface{}) {
    k := datastore.NewKey(c, kind, "some_key", 0, nil)
    _, err := datastore.Put(c, k, &object)
}
save("MyType", c, someMyTypeObject)
```

Example2:

```
func save(kind string, c.appengine.Context, object MyType) {
    k := datastore.NewKey(c, kind, "some_key", 0, nil)
    _, err := datastore.Put(c, k, &object)
}
save("MyType", c, someMyTypeObject)
```

Comment: Ref [Type Assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) (which are similar to reference-type casts in Java or C#) - note the difference when used during an assignment.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand. As I understand it, the first datastore.Put fails because object is of type "interface{}". So I need to cast it to type "MyType" (as defined in the string "kind"). Looking at the page you referenced, I can't see anything similar. Am I being thick? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Oh. Yeah - no. Not like that. It's not possible to use *run-time values* to determine *compile-time/static type information*. You would have to accept the more general contract (e.g. `interface{}`, but it could be more refined) through-and-through, use some form of exhaustive mapping (i.e. Type Assertions) switched off of the value, or otherwise use reflection for the relevant invocations. Basically, one *can't add* static type information based on values.

Comment: Note that there's no such things as "type casting" in Go: only "type *conversions".* This is not a nitpicking: Go underlines that there's no implicit type conversions and hence doing any conversion must be a conscious decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datastore.Put` takes a struct pointer as its 3rd parameter, but you are passing a pointer to an interface which is invalid in this case.

To get around this, you need to pass a pointer when calling `save` and pass that as is to `datastore.Put`.

```
func save(kind string, c appengine.Context, object interface{}) {
    k := datastore.NewKey(c, kind, "some_key", 0, nil)
    _, err := datastore.Put(c, k, object)
}
save("MyType", c, &someMyTypeObject)
```

You can think of this as passing `someMyTypeObject` to `datastore.Put` via `save` without `save` knowing what it is.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was hoping for.